# Replace based on 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I'd like to replace data based on 2 columns.

My query currently looks like this:

```
$query = "REPLACE INTO `".$database."`.`".$table_extras."` (`id`, `multiverseid`, `rulings`, `printings`, `foreignNames`) ";
$query .= "VALUES (".$cardCount.",
    ".$multiverseid.",
    '".addslashes($rulings)."',
    '".addslashes($printings)."',
    '".addslashes($foreignNames)."');";
```

Currently with the above query things get replaced based on 'id'. How can I make it so it's replacing based on 'id' AND 'multiverseid'?

When I created my table it looked like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `extras` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `multiverseid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `rulings` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `printings` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `foreignNames` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `number`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: . . Your table definition does not have a column `id`, although your `replace` references it.

Comment: Fixed typo in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique index on `id`, `multiverseid`:

```
create unique index t_id_multiverseid on table_extras(id, multiverseid);
```

The only issue is the following.  If `id` is already unique or a primary key, then it will continue to be used by the replace.  You would need to drop this constraint.

Comment: If I were to create a new table supporting what you say what would the query look like?

Comment: It would look like your existing table, along with the above index.

Comment: I added more information to the question. Would I just replace PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `number`) your answer if I were to create a new table?

Comment: Yes, that would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE INTO` replaces based on the primary key or unique index.

Create a unique index on id and multiverseid:

```
create unique index table_extras_id_multiverseid on table_extras(id, multiverseid);
```

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) says:

> if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the table's primary key is "id".  This makes it a little hard to parse your question :)

Perhaps your actual intention is to have a table with a primary key across both the id and the multiverseid columns, in which case your REPLACE would work as you require.